# How to send json to highcharts from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm attempting to pass json from a php call via a jQuery ajax call to a highcharts object.

Here is the return from the php script

```
[{"name":"Positive","data":"[1426896000000,0.5,1],[1427760000000,0.333333333333,1],[1427846400000,0.333333333333,1],[1427932800000,0.353553390593,1],[1428278400000,0.408248290464,1],[1428364800000,0.301511344578,1],[1428451200000,0.377964473009,1],[1428537600000,0.686886723927,2],[1428624000000,2.38658259877,7],[1428710400000,0.4472135955,1],[1428883200000,0.333333333333,1],[1429142400000,0.333333333333,1],[1429574400000,0.316227766017,1],[1429747200000,1.10948233661,2],[1429833600000,0.408248290464,1],[1429920000000,1.34375333838,3],[1430092800000,1.13976615407,3]"},{"name":"Negative","data":"[1427673600000,-0.353553390593,1],[1428105600000,-0.353553390593,1],[1428278400000,-1.0850712542,3],[1428537600000,-1.20901527656,3],[1428624000000,-0.377964473009,1],[1428883200000,-0.353553390593,1],[1429056000000,-0.408248290464,1],[1429574400000,-0.377964473009,1],[1429660800000,-0.353553390593,1],[1429747200000,-1,3],[1429833600000,-1.02022005726,3],[1429920000000,-0.755928946018,2],[1430006400000,-0.632455532034,1]"}]
```

I use the following to call getChart:

```
function getChart(searchstring){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "searchString.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {name:searchstring},
    success: function(news) {
        renderPosNegChart(news);
    }
  });
}
function renderPosNegChart(data){
var newschart = {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Test"
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime"
    },
    yAxis: {
    },
    series: [data[0]]
}
$("#newschart").highcharts(newschart);
```

}

Unfortunately, all it's displaying is:
[image]
Eventually, I want it to show both the "Positive" and "Negative" line. I've followed a bunch of tutorials online, but they haven't helped.

If I can clarify anything, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each series data should be an array of arrays and not string.

Example:

```
[{"name":"Positive","data":[[1426896000000,0.5,1], ... ,[1430006400000,-0.632455532034,1]]}]
```

Comment: Can you add any insight into how to build the above object from a mysql call which is passed to json_encode(data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)? Assuming you have a series of rows returned labeled 'x','y','z' (where x is the timestamp)? Ideally, I'd like to do this on the php side.

Comment: I found several problems that were the result of poor understanding of the json object in my php script. I posted the end result below for other's reference, but I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using Kacper's direction, I solved several problems, but I thought it was worth posting my final answer. Essentially, I had cast what should have been arrays to single strings for each data series, rather than letting json_encode do that.

```
// format as array for json conversion
$positive = array();
$positive['name'] = "Positive";
foreach ($positive_news as $key => $value){
    $ts = $key * 1000 - $adjustment; // adjusting for certain timezone
    //$positive['data'][] = "[" . $ts . "," . $value['polarity']. "," . $value['count'] . "]"; // What I had previous
    $positive['data'][] = array($ts, $value['polarity'], $value['count']); // What I changed it to
}
$negative = array();
$negative['name'] = "Negative";
foreach ($negative_news as $key => $value){
    $ts = $key * 1000 - $adjustment;
    //$negative['data'][] = "[" . $keyadj . "," . $value['polarity'] . ","  . $value['count'] . "]"; // What I had previously
    $negative['data'][] = array($ts, $value['polarity'], $value['count']); // What I changed
}

// I also imploded the arrays to strings here (I removed that after reading Kacper's suggesting)

$news = array();
array_push($news, $positive);
array_push($news, $negative);

echo json_encode($news, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); // this is returned to javascript via ajax and sent directly to the below function

function renderPosNegChart(data){
var newschart = {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Test"
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime"
    },
    yAxis: {
    },
    series: [data[0]]
}
$("#newschart").highcharts(newschart);
```

I hope this helps someone else solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your json is wrong

its missing [ and ] on data

should be

```
[{"name":"Positive","data":"[[1426896000000,0.5,1],...[1430006400000,-0.632455532034,1]]"}]
```

and then

```
var newschart = {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Test"
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime"
    },
    yAxis: {
    },
    series: data // or JSON.parse(data)
}
$("#newschart").highcharts(newschart);
```

Check this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdaheL37/)**

Comment: Thanks, but simply adding the brackets did not solve the problem. There has be something being lost in translation.